# Laravel with Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I want to change the name of the column heading.
How do you do?

This is the code in the controller:

```
public function  excelterima($nm_perusahaan){
    if($user = Auth::user()->admin == 2){
        $users = Mstbeasiswa::select('NO_ANGGOTA', 'NM_ANGGOTA', 'GOLONGAN', 'NPK', 'CABANG', 'NM_ANAK', 'NM_SKL', 'id')
                 ->where('flag_terima', '1')
                 ->where('NM_PERUSAHAAN', $nm_perusahaan)
                 ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                 ->get()->toArray();

        //work on the export
        Excel::create($nm_perusahaan, function($excel) use ($users){
            $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use ($users)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($users);
                ob_end_clean();
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
        return redirect('/beasiswaditerima');   
    }else{
      return redirect('/home');   
    }
}
```

output current:

[image: current OUTPUT]

Comment: You can use `select...AS` in your query to achieve this if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks :) .................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [`fromArray()`](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#array) method of `LaravelExcelWorksheet` instance will auto-generate the heading for you based on the given array keys. In order to disable this auto-generation, you need to pass `false` to the fifth parameter (the `$headingGeneration`). Here's the `fromArray()` method signature for your reference:

```
public function fromArray($source = null, $nullValue = null, $startCell = 'A1', $strictNullComparison = false, $headingGeneration = true)
```

You can use the [`row()`](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#rows) method to add a custom heading. Using your code example, now the code should look like this:

```
$users = Mstbeasiswa::select('NO_ANGGOTA', 'NM_ANGGOTA', 'GOLONGAN', 'NPK', 'CABANG', 'NM_ANAK', 'NM_SKL', 'id')
    ->where('flag_terima', '1')
    ->where('NM_PERUSAHAAN', $nm_perusahaan)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

Excel::create($nm_perusahaan, function ($excel) use ($users) {
    $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($users) {
        // Set your custom header.
        $sheet->row(1, ['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5', 'COL6', 'COL7', 'COL8']);

        // Set the data starting from cell A2 without heading auto-generation.
        $sheet->fromArray($users, null, 'A2', false, false);
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Or you can actually just keep the `fromArray()` method calling, but later replace the auto-generated header with `row()` method like so:

```
$excel->sheet('sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($users) {
    $sheet->fromArray($users);

    // Replace the header, but this should come after fromArray().
    $sheet->row(1, ['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4', 'COL5', 'COL6', 'COL7', 'COL8']);
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244168/laravel-excel-not-exporting-in-correct-format?noredirect=1#comment95315360_54244168